# DC Motor Controller: hacking it bidirectional?

Tags: motor, dc-motor, motor-controller, bidirectional

I just picked up two of these DC motor controllers (https://www.amazon.ca/Controller-Yeeco-Universal-0-01-1000W-Generator/dp/B00RZ97DDQ/ref=sr_1_10?dd=1QzB1w0bE3cxmYrmXew-NA%2C%2C&ie=UTF8&qid=1548387512&sr=8-10&keywords=dc%20motor%20controller&refinements=p_90%3A11828088011).

which indicated in the title a "Reverse".  Unfortunately it now seems that this was cut off text, only referring to the reverse polarity protection.  Is there any way to hack this device to get bi-directional performance?

Unfortunately I don't have a datasheet, but I assume most of these devices operate in a similar manner.  Is there any way to proceed?

Comment: What you'll need is an [H-bridge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H_bridge).

Comment: Just buy the right controller: https://www.amazon.ca/dp/B01LYWNQBI

Answer (score 1):

You will not be able to make this unit, itself, become bi-directional.  You can, however, add a component like a DPDT relay to swap the outputs to the motor.

Comment: This should just be comment.....